# SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException when calling .NET framework API using IdentityServer4 bearer token

Tags: c#, jwt, identityserver4, identityserver3

For context:

- Identity Provider running on IdentityServer4
- API running .NET Framework 4.6.1 using the IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation extension to communicate with the identity server.
- Getting a valid access token back for a user from the identity server using Authorization Code + PKCE flow

When I call the API with the access token, the API rejects the access token with the following error message:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Error: 0 : Authentication failed
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '<apiResourceName>'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '<identityProviderBaseUri>/resources' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat.Unprotect(String protectedText)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I can't tell what I should be changing, here is the content of the JWT I'm passing up:

```
{
  "nbf": 1582197029,
  "exp": 1582200629,
  "iss": "<identityProviderBaseUri>",
  "aud": "<apiResourceName>",
  "client_id": "<clientId>",
  "sub": "<userId>",
  "auth_time": 1582197028,
  "idp": "local",
  "email": "<userEmail>",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "<apiResourceName>",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

And here is my IdentityServer3 usage in the .NET Framework API:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "<identityProviderBaseUri>",
    RequiredScopes = new string[] { "<apiResourceName>" }
});
```

Any idea why the middleware is rejecting my access token? Examples I've found (including the identityserver4 quickstart) reflects the above - although the quickstart provides an audience property rather than "RequiredScopes"; other SO posts I've found seem to not match the issue I'm having.

If any further information would be useful let me know.

Thanks

Edit: Removed localhost reference for consistency

Comment: Have you tried setting `EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim` to `true` in the [options](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#identityserver-options)?

Comment: I could do this, but that would mean my other .NET Core services would have to be changed to accommodate for this .NET Framework API I assume? For now, I’ve taken the source code from IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation and changed the ValidAudience property to the audience IdentityServer4 issues.

Comment: @AndyMepham have you managged to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Setting `EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim = true` worked for me.

Comment: Apologies I thought I replied to this - as @eitamal and @Peter say, setting `EmitLegacyResourceAudienceClaim = true` worked.